# Problem avoiding first responder on a NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to change behavior of input fields in a really simple app: 
[image: Simple OSX app]

Whenever i launch the application the first text field get the focus, but i don't want this behavior.

I tried checking "Refuses first responder" in IB. It works but with this option checked i can't move between input fields pressing "tab" button.

What can i do to avoid focus at startup and keep the ability to move with tab keyboard button ?

Comment: Not really an answer since i didn't tried it on MacOS, but on iOS I would use [textfield resignFirstResponder] on load.

Comment: @mindnoise nothing to do, it still maintains focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (previously) accepted answer isn't reliable and doesn't work very well. The other answer with the hidden `NSTextField` isn't very great either because now you have a new element in your Tab order.

The solution I've found works best so far is:

Make the `NSTextField refusesFirstResponder` `YES` on app launch.

Then, in `viewDidAppear` for the controller, go ahead and set `refusesFirstResponder` back to `NO`.

Everything behaves perfect after launch, and I don't have a greedy `NSTextField` stealing first responder on app startup.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, you can add `[window makeFirstResponder:nil];` after awakeFromNib for example in `applicationDidfinishLaunching`.

Answer (score 0):

`window?.makeFirstResponder(nil)` does not work for me - when I check who is the first responder, it is the window (and not a NSTextField) but still, the first NSTextField is selected and active. The solution for me (though I know not the cleanest one) was to create a hidden text field and make it the first responder every time the window did load.

`window?.makeFirstResponder(nil)` worked only when I set all NSTextFields to `RefuseFirstResponder`, but then using Tab to switch between them of course do not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very old post, but in case anyone is still looking.

what you need is to set initialFirstResponder: on your window object - does what it says - selects the field that starts off having the first responder.

Comment: The question is asking how have no initial first responder. Can you clarify how your suggestion can be used to solve that issue?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me,

```
override func viewDidAppear() {

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false) { [weak self] (timer) in
            NSApplication.shared.windows[0].makeFirstResponder(self?.textUsername)
            let tRange = self?.textUsername.currentEditor()?.selectedRange
            self?.textUsername.currentEditor()?.selectedRange = NSMakeRange((tRange?.length)!, 0)
        }
}
```